# Distribute Array on two arrays

Tags: c#

I have an array with different numbers (integers). The length of that array is not set, so it is different every time I run my program. Then I have two other arrays and I want the program to evaluate all possibilites for the distribution of the first array into the other two arrays. For example:

```
Array 1: 1,3,5
```

Now the programm should make the other two arrays for example like this:

```
Array 2: 1,3
Array 3: 5
```

Or like this:

```
Array 2: 1,5
Array 3: 3
```

Comment: This sounds similar to homework seen earlier this week.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Look into Permutations and permuting an array. There are many answers to this on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the placement of an item as a binary digit, then you see that all binary number with the same number of digits as the number of items represent all possible combinations.

So, for three items you have 8 possible combinations:

```
000: [1,3,5], []
001: [3,5], [1]
010: [1,5], [3]
011: [5], [1,3]
100: [1,3], [1]
101: [3], [1,5]
110: [1], [3,5]
111: [], [1,3,5]
```

You can calculate the number of possible combinations using `1 << theArray.Length`.

You can get a specific combination (0 to possible-1) using:

```
public static void GetArrays(int[] arr, int combination, out int[] arr1, out int[] arr2) {
  List<int> a = new List<int>();
  List<int> b = new List<int>();
  foreach (int value in arr) {
    if ((combination & 1) == 1) {
      b.add(value);
    } else {
      a.add(value);
    }
    combination >>= 1;
  }
  arr1 = a.ToArray();
  arr2 = b.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how I can get a specific combination at all :/ I need to create these two arrays and then I have to use them for another thing, then I need to create the next combination and so on. So for this, I want to use a for-loop. The number of possible combinations is clear, but what do I need to exactly have as an input for the "int combination" parameter? I don't really get that, can you maybe give an example?

Comment: @dingoglotz: Calculate the number of possible combinations (cnt), then you loop from `0` to `cnt-1` and call the method to create the two arrays for that specific combination.

Comment: Okay, thanks that helped me out a lot! :) But just one question: Can you explain the operator ">>" and "&"? I googled it, but I can't find a good explanation, I only know that the first one has something to do with the binary number and the second one is a logical AND :/

Comment: @dingoglotz: The `>>` operator does a binary right shift, and the `&` operator used with numbers does a binary and.

Comment: Ok, but can you maybe give me an explanation why you use them in this case or rather what exactly they are doing and how they function? I do not quite get that :/

Comment: @dingoglotz: The expression `combination & 1` isolates the least significant bit in the number, so that you can check if it's one or zero. The `combination >>= 1;` shifts out the least significant bit so that you get the next bit in that position for the next iteration in the loop.